# HTML5 video 'progress' event isn't firing as expected for Chrome anymore

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video, dom-events

I've been developing a set of canvas based video controls for a html5 video. Until recently, everything was working perfectly. Once the video starts buffering, my Javascript event listener for the 'progress' event will update the canvas scrubber.

Recently, I upgraded my OS and the latest build of Chrome (15.0.874.106) doesn't seem to fire the progress event properly. Instead of firing until the video is completely loaded, it stops firing after a very short time. This behavior isn't present in Firefox or on previous builds of Chrome(12).

Is there something that I'm missing?

Here is the testing code that I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<video id="main-player" preload="auto" controls>
<source src='video/atest.mp4' type='video/mp4' />
<source src='video/atest.webm' type='video/webm' />
<source src='video/atest.ogv' type='video/ogg' />
</video>

<script>
var player = document.getElementById('main-player');
player.addEventListener('progress', function(){
    console.log('buffering: [duration: '+player.duration+'] [buffered: '+player.buffered.end(0)+']');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The buffering stops early even if I remove my JS handler completely and only observe the scrubber provided by the video tag.

Comment: I'm having the same issue if it helps that someone else feels your pain.

Comment: I had an issue with this as well. In order to not rely so much on the progress event I used `setInterval()`.